# Jquery Mobile Popup not displaying as a button

Tags: android, jquery, mobile

using version 1.2.1

this is my code

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
         <h3>
            Page 2
        </h3>
 <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" href="#page2" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">
            Back
        </a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
            <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.
                <p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="e">
             <h4>
            footer
        </h4>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have already included files that are necessary.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting the "OPEN POPUP" as an hyper link where as it appears as a button in Jquery docs website

check this link

[Jquery Example Link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/index.html)

Comment: Is that the ONLY code you have for it? HTML wise? If so then you forgot to put a </div> at the bottom

Comment: @DanielMorgan Had soem extra code. </div> is not the problem with this!

Comment: Also probably not another problem, but you've closed a <p> tag wrong... you forgot the forward slash in the close, other than that I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `data-role="button"`
to your 'a' tag

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bujar/JZBq4/)

*You should check out the latest version though. You are using 1.2.1
which is legacy by now
[jQuery Mobile v1.3.1](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)*